# How to set value of input field with NgIf in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am pretty new with Angular 4 and I have probably basic question for someone who is a bit more experienced than me.

I have input field which value needs to be populated when object **user** exists.
So basically I need php function isset() in angular 4.

I tried like this but it is not working.

```
<input class="form-control" type="text"  value="{{ !!user.firstname ? user.firstname : null }}" id="firstname">
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Tnx

Comment: use [(ngModel)] instead of value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [(ngModel)] with input and use elvis operator to check if the user exists or use `*ngIf`

```
<input class="form-control" type="text"  [(ngModel)]=user?.firstName id="firstname">
```

Comment: this one is correct but in slightly different form:

<input class="form-control" type="text"  [ngModel]="user?.firstname" (ngModelChange)=null id="firstname">

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" [value]="user.firstname ? user.firstname : null"  name="firstname" id="firstname">
```